# i++ equivalent in Clojure

Tags: clojure

I'm new to Clojure.

Is there a shortcut to increment a variable in Clojure?

In many languages this would work:

```
i++;
i += 1;
```

In Clojure, I can do:

```
(def i 1)    
(def i (+ i 1))
```

Is this the correct way of incrementing a binding in Clojure?

Are there any shortcuts?

Comment: Notice that I wrote: "this would work" not "it will work" and =+ works in Java.

Comment: Actually `i = i++;` doesn't do anything at all. I mean it doesn't have any effect

Comment: note: when you have to do that you probably doing it wrong. I strongly recommend to read up on functional programming and/or ask for  help on the irc channel, on the mailinglist or here on stackoverflow.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can write `(inc i)` to increment an integer or long.

```
(def i 1)
(def i+1 (inc i))
```

If you need to assign `(inc i)` to `i` itself, then please tell why you want to do that. There will be a more elegant (or idiomatic) solution in clojure in most of the cases.

Comment: Thank you. Could you explain me what is the i+1 in the second line for?

Comment: It is just a variable name. '+' has no special meaning in clojure.

Comment: I don't think he understands that one shouldn't do destructive updates in Clojure.

Comment: Hi, I'd like to make a counter who assigns the number of times someone clicks a button... how to make this counter?

Answer (score 11):

You can use an atom and swap its value,

```
(let [i (atom 0)]
  (println @i)
  (swap! i inc)
  (println @i))
```

will give you

```
0
1
```

Comment: +1 I often find this trick useful, though it's worth adding the caveat that it isn't very good/idiomatic function style to do this!

Answer (score 5):

you can't assign to `i` a new value in clojure, or any other lisp, for what it matters. `i` will in the current context will have one and only one value. `(inc i)` returns a new value that might or might not be binded to a new local variable.

This is the reason why in lisp languages, tail-recursion optimization is so important; because the only way to emulate a loop is with recursion, where on each function invocation the index has a new value. tail-recursion optimization avoids one to exhaust the stack with a really long loop, by converting the recursing in a flat good old loop

clojure gives guarantees that tail-recursion optimizations will happen by using the `recur` function to invoke the same function again. If tail-recursion optimization is not possible, `recur` will give a compile-time error

**Edit** This is the essence of inmutability idioms. There is a strong connection between inmutability and functional-style programming. The reason is that functional programming means "code without side-effects", or to be precise, the only influence of a function in a computation is through its return value. A way to achieve that is making parameters and variables inmutables by default in the sense above. Although by now from the other posters you realise that there are ways around this and not rely on inmutability in clojure

Comment: Tail recursion isn't the only solution for looping/iterating; laziness is another.  `recur` is low-level; most of your looping needs in Clojure can be handled by lazy seqs + `doseq`, `for`, `map`, `reduce` and friends.

Comment: you can change the value of a variable directly in common lisp for example with the setq/setf/etc functions

Comment: i know, but allow him to learn functional style the right way - then, once he masters it, allow him to break it

Comment: I think most lisp dialects allow for mutable variables, there's no point in using false statements to encourage good behaviors.

Comment: For anyone reading this... as @ArthurUlfeldt mentioned. State is mutable in common lisp. The Common Lisp standard does not require implementations to have tail call optimisation (although the main ones do).